# Interesting Identities in First-Order Logic

Tags: logic, big-list, first-order-logic

Are there more identities of this sort (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Provable_identities) that are interesting/non-trivial? It seems that most further work in first-order logic is metalogical, but I wonder how much more there is to understand **in** the logic.  Interesting boolean identities would also satisfy this question.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there are.

Consider :

> $\vdash (\alpha \rightarrow \forall x \beta) \leftrightarrow \forall x (\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$, if $x$ does not occur free in $\alpha$
>
> $\vdash (\exists x \beta \rightarrow \alpha) \leftrightarrow \forall x (\beta \rightarrow \alpha)$, if $x$ does not occur free in $\alpha$
>
> $\vdash (\forall x \beta \rightarrow \alpha) \leftrightarrow \exists x (\beta \rightarrow \alpha)$, if $x$ does not occur free in $\alpha$
>
> $\vdash (\alpha \rightarrow \exists x \beta) \leftrightarrow \exists x (\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$, if $x$ does not occur free in $\alpha$

Basically, they are inter-derivable form the corresponding ones with $\land$ and $\lor$.

*Are them interesting ?*

In the foolowing book : George Tourlakis, [Mathematical Logic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470280743) (2008), the mathematical logic is treated as an *equational calculus*, i.e. with $\leftrightarrow$ (or $\equiv$) as "basic" connective.

There you can find a huge amount of "identities" with their proof.